# correct NSNumberFormatter for many cases in swift

Tags: swift

i am having some problems with NSNumberFormatter and Significant Digits in swift.

```
var test1 : Float = 0.2345
var test2 : Float = 1234.4567
var test3 : Float = 2.234234
```

i want to show this values in 3 different labels (label1, label2, label3). i am looking for NSNumberFormatter so my variables could look like:

- 0.24
- 1234.46
- 2.23

so all of them have 2 digits after "."
and if first digit is 0 it is visible

right now my code is

```
  var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
  formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
  formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true
  formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 1
  formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 4
label1.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(var1)
label2.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(var2)
label3.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(var3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave

```
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 1
```

and add:

```
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
```

remove the rest:

```
  formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true
  formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 4
```

It should gives you just number with 2 decimal places.

Comment: in this case for 0.23 i see only .23 - there is no zero

Comment: @moonvader I believe just maximumFractionDigits and .DecimalStyle would sort that.

Comment: so formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 1 is not necessary?

Comment: @moonvader I believe so but not 100% sure, you can try it.

Comment: Brilliant! You can also embellish:

let fmtr = NSNumberFormatter()
fmtr.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
fmtr.usesGroupingSeparator = true
fmtr.minimumFractionDigits = 0
fmtr.maximumFractionDigits = 1
fmtr.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false